# What is the big-O cpu time of Euclid's Algorithm of "Greatest common divisor of two numbers"

Tags: algorithm-analysis, big-o

Looking at Euclid's algorithm for the "Greatest common divisor of two numbers", I'm trying to divine the big-O cpu time for numbers K, and N. Can anybody help?

This is the algorithm as I understand it..

Where:

- max(A,B) = the greater of A or B such that: min(10,3) = 10
- min(A,B) = the smaller of A or B such that: min(10,3) = 3
- modulus(A,B) = the remainder of A divided by B such that: modulus(10, 3) = 1

The algorithm is:

1. r = modulus(max(K,N), min(K,N))
2. if r = 0

   - then GCD is max(K,N)
   - else:

     - max(K,N) = r
     - go to step 1

It appears to me that due to the division occurring, it can't be a linear algorithm which is why it's useful as something more efficient than a naive implementation that just tries all the possibilities from 0 to min(K,N). But I can't quite figure out just what the runtime is.

Any pointers would be very helpful!

Comment: Depends on your implementation. What have you tried so far for the analysis? Show us your GCD implementation.

Answer (score 9):

This answer draws from the answers within the SO question [Algorithm complexity with input is fix-sized](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2025543/289086)

The first thing to do is to rewrite this as pseudo code with line numbers so that we can talk about specific loops.

```
1) def GCD(x, y):
2)    while x != y:
3)       if x < y:
4)          x, y = y - x, x
5)       else:
6)          x, y = x - y, x
7)     return x
```

This is a form of the subtraction based call of the [euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) rather than the recursive form / modulus form (which the question alludes to).  That one, for the sake of completeness is (different numbering so that the two are not confused):

```
a) def GCD(x, y):
b)   if y = 0
c)       return x
d)   else
e)       return GCD(y, x % y)
```

For the subtractive method, the worst case is where the two numbers are [coprime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers) which has the property of GCD(x,y) = 1.  An example of coprime integers is 15 and 8.

None of the statements of lines 2 .. 6 are anything other than O(1).  There is no multiple loop.  The question is one of what the the loop count is.

For any call `gcd(n,1)`, this will take n-1 loops.  Each step, the path will be 1, 2, 5, 6.  Line 6 will decrement n by 1, until n = 1.  As stated, this is n-1 loops.  As this is the worst case, one has gcd(n,1) = O(n).

So, for GCD(15,1), there are 14 loops.  This is also a very boring function that only has one variable.  What if we make it interesting by doing, as asked, GCD(x,y) where they are coprime?

As mentioned above, GCD(15,8) = 1.  How many loops does it do then?

```
GCD(15,8)
  x = 15, y = 8
    x, y = 15 - 8, 8
  x = 7, y = 8
    x, y = 8 - 7, 8
  x = 1, y = 8
  (7 more steps)
```

The important thing to notice here is that this is more steps than 8.  The asymptotic worst case is related to the *max* of the two parameters.  The actual running time may have other factors mixed in - GCD(15,2) is twice as 'fast' as GCD(15,1), but that's a constant factor which still keeps at at O(n).

The asymptotic worst case for this form of GCD(x,y) is O(max(x,y)).

---

But wait, you say... the other form of GCD, the recursive one... GCD(15,1) is the best case, you get GCD(1, 15 % 1 = 0) after one step.

This area has a special place in the history of computation.  In 1844 a proof was published by Gabriel Lamé on the running time of the Euclidean algorithm. This marks the beginnings of computation complexity theory.  For this, the worst case is pairs of Fibonacci numbers and it runs in no more than 5k steps where  k = log<sub>10</sub>(min(x,y)).  This is known as [Lamé's Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LamesTheorem.html).  Actually, the 5 is a simplification - the actual number is ln(10)/lnϕ ≈ 4.785 where ϕ is the [golden ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio).  And yes, the math for this is getting over my head.

Some reading on Lamé's Theorem:

- [Help understanding the proof of Lame's Theorem.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/452139/help-understanding-the-proof-of-lames-theorem) from Math.SE
- [Lamé's Theorem - the Very First Application of Fibonacci Numbers](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/blue/LamesTheorem.shtml)
- [Lamé's Theorem from The Primes](http://primes.utm.edu/glossary/xpage/LamesTheorem.html)

Read the Math.SE one - there's no way I can get all of that in here to explain that part.

Suffice to say, this form of GCD(x,y) is O(log(min(x,y)))

---

Of special note, there's also a binary form of GCD that works with bit manipulations.  Read about it at [Binary GCD algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_GCD_algorithm) on wikipedia.  It potentially runs a bit faster on computers because the operations are all bitwise which run faster than subtraction or division.  This one is O(n<sup>2</sup>) where n is the number of bits in the larger of the two numbers - please note the change in the definition of n between this and the previous forms of the analysis.  Despite the larger O, it is between 15%  to 60% faster (Knuth 1998 - TAOCP vol 2, 3rd edition) depending on architecture because of the simpler instructions (if I read that right).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor
Binary Method
O((log a+log b)^{2}).

This is years later, The wikipedia linked shows Binary Method as a smaller big oh than stated in previous comment.

No one, so far on this page, has put examples proving these big oh's for binary method.

I might put a proof when I figure out the correct answer.